# Emails not sending to one specific domain

Tags: centos, smtp, aws

We have a AWS server where emails are delivered to domains other than our own domain. I have confirm that I can send an email to my gmail account but I can't send to my hosted gmail account.

So for example, I can send to myemail@gmail.com but not me@mydomain.com

The server is hosting mydomain.com

I have successfully integrated Amazon SES and I am still able to send emails to my gmail account but not to my own domain.

```
 /usr/sbin/sendmail -f brent@mydomain.com myemail@gmail.com
This is a giant test
```

This works, but the following doesn't

```
 /usr/sbin/sendmail -f brent@mydomain.com sales@mydomain.com
This test is bigger than the previous test
```

My DNS is hosted on Amazon Route 53.
My Email is hosted at Google
My Website is hosted at Amazon on an Ec2 instance.
My Webserver is an Amazon AMI instance

```
cat /etc/*-release
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2014.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2014.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2014.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.09
```

I am thinking my mail is getting captured by my own server and not being delivered but I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 2):

These steps worked

Steps:

```
vim /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

at the end:

```
define(`MAIL_HUB', `example.com.')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `example.com.')dnl
```

and then:

```
sendmailconfig (or /etc/mail/make depending on your distro)
service sendmail restart
```

testing:

```
echo -e "To: user@example.com\nSubject: Test\nTest\n" | sendmail -bm -t -v
echo -e "To: user\nSubject: Test\nTest\n" | sendmail -bm -t -v
```

From here: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/65365/disable-local-delivery-in-sendmail